# Cannot open Chrome or reinstall the program anymore

Tags: google-chrome

I’m using Google Chrome 8.0.552.237. And just found myself cannot open or maximize the program anymore. No matter how I hit the “Maximize” command it just stick to the Task Bar and won’t show up.

I don’t know what’s wrong here, but I want at least restore the bookmarks that saved on Chrome. Do you have any idea?

Thanks very much.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bookmarks should be saved on these folders (not completely sure, since you are using a really old Chrome version).

It's a plain text file with JSON syntax.

### Windows XP

```
Google Chrome: C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks
```

### Windows 7 or Vista

```
Google Chrome: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Chromium: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default\Bookmarks

Comment: Thanks,Martin. I just installed a new chrome-based browser, it runs as fast as the original Chrome. And I'm working on extract those URLs from the Bookmarks file you mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Probably Chrome has gone unresponsive. The bookmarks you've created should have been already saved. Only if it "crashed" during the save, the latest might not exist anymore.
You could try to kill all instances of Chrome by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Esc (takes you to Task Manager), click on 'Processes' tab, find all chrome.exe processes and close them.
After that you should be able to restart Chrome or reinstall it.